# Firefox broken after permission changes

Tags: permissions, firefox

I had recently changed some permissions of folders within docker to enable logs to be created, however somewhere along the route it seems like I had messed up permissions for `/var/lib/snapd/hostfs`.

When I try to launch firefox, nothing happens. Trying to open it through the command line prompts `/var/lib/snapd/hostfs is not owned by root`. All other things I've tried have had no impact and reinstalling ubuntu isn't a viable option.

Comment: Did you also change it to be 755 permissions? What does `ls -ld /var/lib/snapd/hostfs/` show? Did you also bork permissions elsewhere?

Comment: It was changed to be 755 I belive. That command returns `drwxr-xr-x 2 root www-data 4096 Dec  1 08:52 /var/lib/snapd/hostfs/`. I initially tried to change `/var/www/` for storage within Laravel, but I believe this is where it went wrong.